# DB2 Merge SQL iSeries

Tags: php, sql, db2-400

I created this function to update or insert a row based on if a row already exist, or not; the error I am getting is VAR1 is not a variable. This is my first time setting up a merge in this fashion on a iSeries and DB2.  Hope someone can help, thanks to all that takes the time to do so.

```
function mergeRecord($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6){

db2RunSql("
        MERGE INTO schema.tableName AR
  USING (VALUES (:var1, :var2, var3, :var4, :var5, :var6)
    FOR :var1 ROWS)
    AS AC (VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR4, VAR5, VAR6)
  ON (AR.VAR1 = AC.VAR1 AND AR.VAR4 = AC.VAR4 AND AR.VAR6 = AC.VAR6)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET VAR1=?, VAR2=?, VAR3=?, VAR4=?, VAR5=?, VAR6=?
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (:var1, :var2, :var3, :var4, :var5, :var6)
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6)
    );
}
```

Comment: The colons in `:var1, :var2, ...` look like you are trying to embed SQL in a high level language like `RPG`. The php tag and variables in the form `$v ar1, $var2, ...` look like you are talking about PHP. And I can't find `db2RunSql()` in any of the documentation. So what are you trying to do, and what language. If PHP, which database extension are you using? and how is `db2RunSql()` defined?

Comment: Are you perhapse assuming PDO and doing a mix of named parameters and traditional `?` parameter markers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
function mergeRecord($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6){

db2RunSql("
  MERGE INTO schema.tableName AR
    USING (VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?))
      AS AC (VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR4, VAR5, VAR6)
    ON (ar.var1, ar.var4, ar.var6) = (ac.var1, ac.var4, ac.var6)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET (ar.var2, ar.var3, ar.var5) = (ac.var2, ac.var2, ac.var5)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT VALUES (ac.var1, ac.var2, ac.var3, ac.var4, ac.var5, ac.var6)",
        array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6)
    );
}
```

I think you are trying to insert too many parameter markers in your example when you could simply be using columns in the source (USING) table as update or insert values.

**NOTE:** This is just a guess as I am not sure what `db2RunSql()` does. It is not a standard function, and you have not provided a definition of it.